# SQL lookup table to JOIN and produce dataset

Tags: sql

I need to produce a target table structure by reading the configuration and applying it on a dataset in plain SQL.
I have two data tables in the below format

```
T1
|Col1|Col2|
|1   |12  |
|2   |13  |
|3   |14  |
|4   |15  |
|5   |16  |

T2
|Col1|Col2|
|11  |22  |
|21  |23  |
|31  |24  |
|41  |25  |
|51  |26  |
```

And a config table to read from as given below

```
TC
|Tbl|Col |Val|Text|
|T1 |Col1|1  |A   |
|T1 |Col1|3  |B   |
|T1 |Col2|15 |A   |
|T2 |Col2|26 |A   |
|T2 |Col1|11 |B   |
```

I need to come up with the below target tables

```
TGT1
|Col1|Col2|Text|
|1   |12  |A   |
|2   |13  |NULL|
|3   |14  |B   |
|4   |15  |A   |
|5   |16  |NULL|

TGT2
|Col1|Col2|Text|
|11  |22  |B   |
|21  |23  |NULL|
|31  |24  |NULL|
|41  |25  |NULL|
|51  |26  |A   |
```

The logic is to read the complete T1 and T2 and produce the Text field as provided in the TC table (Tbl and Col are referring to the actual table and columns in the setup)

I am totally confused on how to produce this output. Can anyone please provide me some pointers to start with? If this helps anyone to fiddle with!

```
WITH 
T1(Col1,Col2) AS 
(SELECT 1,12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,13 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,14 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,15 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,16 ),
T2(Col1,Col2) AS
(SELECT 11,22 UNION ALL
SELECT 21,23 UNION ALL
SELECT 31,24 UNION ALL
SELECT 41,25 UNION ALL
SELECT 51,26 ),
TC (Tbl,Col,Val,Text) AS
(SELECT 'T1','Col1',1,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'T1','Col1', 3,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 'T1','Col2',15,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'T2','Col2',26,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'T2','Col1',11,'B' )
SELECT ????
```

Comment: Perhaps look into a cross join

Comment: What type of database is this? Does it need to be ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a `left join`.  Here is one method, using `t1` as an example:

```
select t1.*, tc.text
from t1 left join
     tc
     on (t1.col1 = tc.val and tc.tbl = 't1' and tc.col = 'Col1') or
        (t1.col2 = tc.val and tc.tbl = 't1' and tc.col = 'Col2') or
        (t1.col3 = tc.val and tc.tbl = 't1' and tc.col = 'Col3') ;
```

You would approach `t2` the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The following is my attempt:

```
SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2, TC.Text
FROM 
    T1 LEFT JOIN TC
        ON TC.Tbl = 'T1' 
        AND (
            T1.Col1 = TC.Val AND TC.Col = 'Col1' 
            OR T1.Col2 = TC.Val AND TC.Col = 'Col2'
        )

SELECT T2.Col1, T2.Col2, TC.Text
FROM 
    T2 LEFT JOIN TC
        ON TC.Tbl = 'T2' 
        AND (
            T2.Col1 = TC.Val AND TC.Col = 'Col1' 
            OR T2.Col2 = TC.Val AND TC.Col = 'Col2'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  T1.Col1,
  T1.Col2,
  TC.[Text]
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN TC ON TC.Tbl = 'T1'
             AND TC.VAL = CASE TC.Col 
                          WHEN 'Col1' THEN T1.Col1
                          WHEN 'Col2' THEN T1.Col2
                          END;

SELECT
  T2.Col1,
  T2.Col2,
  TC.[Text]
FROM T2
LEFT JOIN TC ON TC.Tbl = 'T2'
             AND TC.VAL = CASE TC.Col 
                          WHEN 'Col1' THEN T2.Col1
                          WHEN 'Col2' THEN T2.Col2
                          END;
```

**Here is a working SQLFiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b7c0/9/0

Answer (score 1):

I would do something more like this:

```
with u as
(select
tc.tbl, tc.col, tc.val, [Text]
from
tc inner join
(select 't1' as tbl, 'col1' as col, col1 as val from t1 union
select 't1' as tbl, 'col2' as col, col2 as val from t1 union
select 't2' as tbl, 'col1' as col, col1 as val from t2 union
select 't2' as tbl, 'col2' as col, col2 as val from t2) s on
tc.tbl = s.tbl and
tc.col = s.col and
tc.val = s.val)

select 't1' as tbl, col1, col2, [text] from 
t1 left outer join 
u on
tbl = 't1' and
case when col='col1' then col1 else col2 end = val
union
select 't2', col1, col2, [text] from 
t2 left outer join 
u on
tbl = 't2' and
case when col='col1' then col1 else col2 end = val
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b7c0/29)

Comment: Further information on common table expressions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql